# Spark 2.0 - "Table or view not found" when querying Hive.( Spark cant see hive tables )

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

When querying Hive via `spark-shell` 2.0:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename")
```

It throws an error:

```
16/08/13 09:24:17 INFO execution.SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `schemaname`.`tablename`; line 1 pos 14
...
```

Hive access seems to be properly configured via `hive-site.xml`. In shell Spark is printing:

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir")
res5: String = /user/hive/warehouse
```

Inside `conf/hive-site.xml`, Hive is configured and its configurations can be accessed on Spark. When listing the databases, it shows the existing `default` database. But it doesn't show the tables that are inside `default`.

```
scala> spark.catalog.listDatabases.show(false)
+-------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|name   |description     |locationUri                                  |
+-------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|default|default database|hdfs://hdfs-server-uri:8020/user/hive/warehouse|
+-------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+

scala> spark.catalog.listTables("default").show()
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|name|database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Why can't Spark see my Hive Tables?

Comment: are you using embedded derby(default configuration) or external database for your hive metastore?

Comment: @Addy external one. In SPARK_HOME/conf I have `hive-site.xml`, which contains metastore uri set in `hive.metastore.uris`.

Comment: I've found the solution (since question is marked as on hold, I'm posting it here in case anyone has the same problem):

The reason was lack of Hive dependency jars in Spark classpath - looks like it silently fails if they're not there.

Comment: Hi @ArkadiuszKomarzewski, I'm running into the same error. Can you please tell what jars did you copy on what path?

Comment: @pikoooz I don't remember (can try checking it later), but for now I suggest using Spark distribution pre-built with your Hadoop version from [official downloads](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) + not forgetting about `SparkSession#enableHiveSupport()` - let me know if it helped.

Comment: You may have missed this step: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_spark-guide/content/spark-config-hive.html It solved my similar issue!

Comment: as mentioned by @ArkadiuszKomarzewski, add the enableHiveSupport() before getOrCreate() while building your sparkSession and you are good to go.