# cannot find table from hive using spark-submi

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

this is my simple code.

```
spark.sql("select * from default.some_table")
```

when using this code in zeppelin or spark-shell then it works perfectly.

But, try on ***spark-submit*** command

following error occurred

```
diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found:: `default`.`some_table`; line 1 pos 14;
```

any help?

this is my spark submit command

```
spark-submit --class com.any.any.App  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster app.jar
```

thanx

Comment: Here may be the answer in this link --
```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931303/spark-2-0-table-or-view-not-found-when-querying-hive```

Comment: @Rani thanx, but in my case, I can retrieve all my tables using 
   `spark.catalog.listTables("default").show()` so it needs different solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Solved it!! need to set ***hive.metastore.warehouse.dir*** when create SparkSession!!

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("mbp stream layer on nuri cluster")
  .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```